# Can't import Numpy in Jupyter notebook (RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm following along with https://www.firstpythonnotebook.org/ (I'm a beginner in using Jupyter and generally with using python, pip, etc). Basically the steps I've followed so far are:

1. Install pipenv, make new environment in the desired directory
2. `pipenv install jupyterlab`
3. `pipenv install pandas` ([on this page](https://www.firstpythonnotebook.org/pandas/index.html))

When opening my first notebook and running `import pandas`, though, I get an error that seems to come from importing `numpy` as a dependency of `pandas`.

```
import pandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-notebook-again-duPr9W-R/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append(f"{dependency}: {e}")

~/.local/share/virtualenvs/test-notebook-again-duPr9W-R/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py in <module>
    284                     "that provided NumPy.\n{}\n".format(
    285                         error_message))
--> 286                 raise RuntimeError(msg)
    287     del _mac_os_check
    288 

RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Numpy gets installed in the environment by default when installing pandas, I believe, but it seems like something goes wrong with this installation? I have no idea what "Accelerate" or "Polyfit" are, and to be honest trying to read what they are feels like I'm in way over my head. There must be a simpler solution here than trying to understand those things as a total beginner, right? Anyone know why this may be happening?

Comment: Got this same error when trying to pip install matplotlib recently.

Comment: different error, but same problem: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/403073/cant-install-pandas-on-bigsur-with-pip ; check this: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15947

Comment: I'm setting up a new computer and I just installed Jupyter Notebook. I installed pandas via `pip3 install pandas` and when I try to import it into Jupyter, I get the same exact error: 

>RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned

Answer (score 1):

Worked like a charm on my Mac.

https://gist.github.com/yatsu/47bdde35e8abbe7d14bbe730342aa9e0

Numpy 1.19.2 with Python 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error too, tried pipenv install matplotlib. Using Python 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

The link that Thomas has in his comment is correct. I rolled back Python to an earlier build, namely Python 3.8.5 from July 20, 2020 and I was able to install pandas using `pip3 install pandas` and then `pip3 install notebook` and lastly `import pandas, numpy` into Jupyter.